# How apache2 can deny connections to a domain which is not hosted

Tags: apache

I am hosting website [iplocation.io](https://iplocation.io/) on a cloud server. I found a domain https://chrissloey.com/index.php which opens my website within it.

Now from what I understand, chrissloey.com has pointed it A record to my server ip and my apache2 server is not denying connection to it and allow's to open iplocation.io website content like its own.

I want apache2 to deny connections to any other domain and only allow my own domain to server content.

Attached is apache conf file for iplocation.io

```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin email@email.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/public_html
        ServerName iplocation.io
        ServerAlias www.iplocation.io
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/apache-error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


        <Directory /var/www/public_html>
                    Options  FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                    AllowOverride All
                    Require all granted
        </Directory>

    </VirtualHost>


    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName iplocation.io
        ServerAdmin email@email.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/public_html
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /path-to-csr
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /path-to-key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /path-to-ca


        <Directory /var/www/public_html>
                    Options  FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                    AllowOverride All
                    Require all granted                
        </Directory>

    </VirtualHost>
    </IfModule
```

Comment: Two obvious options: 1. detect the requested host name using the rewriting module and throw an error if you want to or 2. define a default host denying all requests and a specialized host service your own content. Both options are documented and you will find lots of examples for that.

Comment: But there is an option that probably makes much more sense: accept those users! Just implement a redirection rule. Forward all requests to domains that are _not_  your own to your own domain using an external redirection. Then that other site even brings users to you.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the two comments I think the combination makes most sense:

Configure httpd to respond with redirect (301) to all incoming requests. This could be done on the 'root' host.
Configure a virtualhost listening to your domain only, and this one would serve your real content only.

This will work unless the other site requests your content and then integrates it into their responses. But as you said someone else simply put up a DNS A record.